# DC/DC converter noise reduction circuit

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, pcb-design, inductor, emc

I have 4 MEAN WELL [NID-100-5](https://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=NID100) in parallel to power 5 V digital LEDs.

They will each receive a maximum of 2 A @24 V (max. total 8 A) and will each output a maximum of 9 A @5 V.

The 24 V supply cable is 10 m long.

Question A: (the question is two-fold)

1. Can I make the attached circuit 4 times on one PCB, I will be putting every component on it 4 times in parallel?
2. Can I put the Vin part of the circuit at the beginning of the 10 m cable or should I put it in the end near the NID-100-5?

If both are answered, which capacitors and inductors should I use?

I have 6 fixtures with each 4 NID-100-5s so it's beneficial to make a single EMC reduction PCB.

Question B: The L1 with the Z symbol is unclear which component I should use. [The reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ElectricalEngineering/comments/a853u2/what_does_this_inductor_symbol_mean/) is unclear about it being a differential mode choke or a common mode choke.

What inductor component should I use? A mouser link would help a ton.

[image: NID-100-5 EMC circuit]

Added wiring digram for clarity NID-500 Share the same supply and are connected to the LED strip at approx 1 m intervals
[image: Wiring diagram]

Comment: `I have 4 MEAN WELL NID-100-5 in parallel` Do you mean directly parallel (i.e. + terminals shorted together and - terminals shorted together)? If so, the datasheet doesn't say anything about whether the modules can be connected in parallel. Might be problematic. As for your main question(s), you need to specify your EMC requirements first and compare your initial measurements to the requirements i.e. what standards are your target? Have you taken any measurements? At what frequencies did you see the emissions exceeded the limits? Or did your circuit have conducted / radiated immunity problem?

Comment: Z symbol means common mode choke.